# iOS IAP- need advice on premium version of app

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I've followed a tutorial to create an IAP for my game.  My goal is to have a "Remove Ads" button.  Once the user gets this IAP, the remove ads button disappears, and ads stop showing.  On future launches of the app this purchase is loaded automatically.

I've got the basics of this down, but here are my issues.

1. I've created a sandboxed user, and every time I start my app it's asking me to login to itunes.  I'd figure it should really only be asking me to login when I'm deciding to purchase the app.  Is this related to me being a sandboxed user?
2. I'm also restoring purchases on every app launch.  This seems to be happening automatically without login.. so why is it me asking to login every time?  Should I be utilizing NSUserDefaults to avoid restoring purchases in the future?

Here is my code so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // storekit delegation
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    self.getProductInfo()
}

func getProductInfo(){
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: self.productID))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
//        else {
//            please enable in app purchases
//        }
    }
```

**Delegate methods**

```
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    var products = response.products

    if products.count != 0 {
        self.product = products[0] as? SKProduct
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    if queue.transactions.count != 0 {
        if let purchase = queue.transactions[0] as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            if purchase.payment.productIdentifier == self.productID {
                println("you bought it already")
            }
        }
    } 
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction in transactions as [SKPaymentTransaction] {

        switch transaction.transactionState {

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
//                self.unlockFeature()
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: You don't have to restore a purchase on every launch of the app, instead you should have a restore button for that and apple won't accept your app if you don'r provide a restore button for non-consumable IAP

Comment: i'm assuming this restore button would apply to a new install.  Couldnt this happen automatically without the user hitting the restore button?  If my app is smart enough to know that this user already made the purchase, do they really need log in?  Couldnt this all happen automatically?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, the login requests are related to the sandbox user

2) You should be checking the receipt each time, not restoring purchases or storing separate local lists of purchases. See Apple's Receipt Validation Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1

Restoring purchases should be a user-initiated operation, with dedicated UI (a restore button in the store somewhere) separate from checking if a purchase has been made.

Comment: this is great info.. as much as I love reading documentation, some simple examples would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be utilizing NSUserDefaults to avoid restoring purchases in the future?

You need to avoid `NSUserDefaults` for IAP. `NSUserDefaults` are stored in plist in binary format, with no encryption. If you need security you should use KeyChain. It encodes values and is best way to save some security information.